# How to use "advantageous" instead of "advantage" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Suppose I want to reword the sentence below

> What is the advantage of X over Y.

Can I say

> What is advantageous **in** X over Y?

If no, how can use "advantageous"? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Is the preposition **in** a good choice? What preposition should be used?

Comment: If you can use a shorter word to convey your meaning, just use the shorter word.

Comment: @The Photon Thanks but, It's not just about conveying my intention, it's more about learning english.

Comment: @ThePhoton's suggestion *is* sound advice for using English well. :) That said, the answers below are good summaries of how to use this word. Between T's and Maulik's almost the full range is nearly covered. The most natural in my grammar though might be the unmentioned cleft sentence: "It is advantageous to strike early."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something can be advantageous.

> X is advantageous.

Something *about* X (one or more of its features/characteristics/qualities) can be advantageous.

> What is advantageous about  X?

If you are skeptical about X and need convincing:

> What is so advantageous about X?

Something can be **more** advantageous **than** something else.

> Why is X more advantageous than Y?
>
> What makes X more advantageous than Y?
>
> What is it about X that makes it more advantageous than Y?

You can ask what makes X better than Y:

> What is advantageous about X **over** Y?

Comment: Can you get me the grammar reference for this?

Comment: @Maulik V: What do you mean by "the" grammar reference, or by "this", for that matter?

Answer (score 2):

As I looked upon authentic sources (dictionaries), I learned that the word *advantageous (adj.)* either takes the preposition ***'to'*** or it takes a direct noun.

> *Free exchange of goods was advantageous to all. [+ to]* - [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/advantageous)

and...

> *Her experience placed her in an advantageous position to apply for the job.* - [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advantageous)

I couldn't come across an example or the usage of the word the way you want. This means, `What is advantageous in X over Y?`- you can't say!

You also asked about the preposition used: it's *'to'*

Though 'advantage' and 'advantageous' may *look same,* they aren't. Or at least, they are not interchangeable because one is noun, another is adjective.

**You asked: How to use “advantageous” instead of “advantage” in a sentence**

> The latest system offers many advantages 
>  The latest system is pretty advantageous to us

Check there, you need a preposition and then the object.